# JavaScript - Creating function object from function definition in a String

Tags: javascript, string, function

In JavaScript, is there any way to create function object from function definition in a String?

Something similar to a JSON.parse for creating JSON from a String.

```
const parseFunction = (str)=> {
   // What should be implemented here?
   return func;
}
let funStr = parseFunction("function replacer(arg1) {console.log(arg1)}");
```

Comment: Do you mean `eval`?

Comment: Why do you need this? Where is the function definition coming from?

Comment: You could use the Function constructor? `new Function(str)`? Just pass the function body instead

Comment: @felix-kling working on a JSON template based dashboard configuration.. couldn't find a better validator(lints) that accepts function as a value for a key.. also having function inside JSON makes it as an invalid JSON.. I want to hold function as value and also a valid JSON. So, just looking for options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `eval` invites a lot of security risks in your application. Javascript now has a alternative to that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

```
const parseFunction = (str)=> {
   return Function('"use strict";return (' + str + ')')();
}
let funStr = parseFunction("function(arg1) {console.log(arg1)}");
```

You try playing around it this is just for reference.

Comment: Just to make sure that people don't get the wrong impression: The only difference between direct `eval` and `Function()()` is the fact that the latter executes the code in global scope. There isn't anything else that makes it fundamentally more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Just improvising Mr.@abhishek-sharma answer,

The function created using `Function('"use strict";return (' + str + ')')();` will not be closure of current scope. In case if anyone want to access some variable in the current scope,

```
const parseFunction = (str) => {
  return Function(
    'varNameInStr',
    'return function() {return (' + str + ')}',
  )(varInCurrScope)();
};
parseFunction("function(){console.log(varNameInStr)}")
```